# How do I add amd64 (x86_64) packages to apt sources on a non-x86_64 system?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, architecture, cpu-architecture

I have an ARM64 architecture Ubuntu 22.04 system and I would like to have support for emulating x86_64 (what Ubuntu calls amd64). I have already added amd64 as a supported architecture in dpkg using `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64` and I have already installed Box64 by following their instructions.

However, I have no idea how to make apt download amd64 packages. My `/etc/apt/sources.list` has entries like this:

```
deb [arch=arm64] http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted
```

I have tried changing the square brackets to `[arch=arm64,amd64]`, but then `apt update` gives me many 404 not found errors. When I visit [the website](http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/) that the sources.list refers to, I see many architectures, but amd64 is not one of them. I noticed that the URL has `ports` in it twice, is there a non-ports URL I have to add? Is this documented somewhere? I've been searching for awhile and I haven't found out what lines are supposed to go in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "ports" is just that: ports of Ubuntu to different architectures (other than the "standard" x86_64). For amd64 you would use `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Do you know how I could install `libglib2.0-bin` for both amd64 and arm64 at the same time? Apt keeps wanting to remove one when I install the other.

Comment: is this what you require? https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libglib2.0-bin